# What about data visualization novices?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The [Help/Tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) page says,

> Cross Validated is a question and answer site for statisticians,
>   machine teachers, data analysts, data miners and data visualization
>   experts.

(Aside: Should "machine teachers" be there? -- it's not in the other versions of the tag line.)

What about data visualization *novices*? Do such users and their questions belong on CV or some existing SE site? If not, should CV invite them or should a new SE site be created for them? Looks like there is a [deleted Infographics and Data Visualization proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11508/infographics-and-data-visualization) in Area 51 in case anyone has enough rep to see it.

On one hand, I like data visualization living in CV because many data visualization issues are tightly coupled to data analysis. For instance, choosing the right summarization level and making valid comparisons.

On the other hand, there are other aspects not tied to analysis, such as choosing a color scheme, understanding efficient layout, software tools, and visual perception.

I ask because I noticed this new site, [Help Me Viz](http://helpmeviz.com/), is trying to use the WordPress engine for something similar to SE in this area.

Comment: That is quite a typo. I remember [similar discussion coming up before](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/879/1036) and changing the FAQ to not seem so exclusive to experts.

Comment: I suggest a wording such as ... people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining and data visualization.

Comment: I think @NickCox has come up with the right wording

Comment: Because the "machine teachers" is such a glaring error and your point about experts seems incontrovertible, I have proceeded to make the edit suggested by @Nick Cox.  Please do not let that preclude further discussion or suggestions!

Comment: Thanks @whuber. There are at least two other occurrences of the tag line: in the Stack Exchange/all sites drop down in the upper left (if you are not logged in) and on the statsqa twitter profile.

I do hope to see other discussion regarding pure data visualization questions fitting in to CV, and how to encourage the desired result.

Comment: xan, if you (or anyone else) would provide links to any such occurrences I will endeavor to make the fixes. Moderators might or might not be able to do this but I'll try.

Comment: The twitter profile is at https://twitter.com/statsqa.
The dropdown text may have the same source as going to http://stackexchange.com/sites# and clicking on the Cross Validated icon.

Comment: @xan I'm afraid that CV moderators can't alter Twitter profile (it is not maintained nor curated by any of us), or SE main profile page.

Comment: That makes sense, @chl. Could you contact the SE devs? I assume they can do this. Or should the question be migrated to meta.SE?

Comment: I can get this to the right hands - would someone just give me an exact description of what needs to be changed on the Twitter profile?

Comment: +1 on the original issue. A great deal of data visualisation questions are pretty complex. Where would someone who tinkers around with d3.js and ggplot2 but does not necessarily come from the statistics community find a home? Dataviz has gotten a lot more accessible recently, this board hasn't always ;)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller, the request is to change "statisticians, data analysts, -miners and -visualization experts" to "people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining and data visualization" in the statsqa twitter profile.

Comment: @xan, statsqa is not an official Stack Exchange twitter account - that's stackstats. statsqa needs to be updated to reflect that it is **not** an official account (and whatever other updates you guys want made). We can change stackstats for you, though.

Answer (score 12):

I'm running this by the Community Team just in case there are any objections I can't come up with, but overall, this seems reasonable.

To summarize, this community is in favor of changing its description to:

> Cross Validated is a question and answer site for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining and data visualization.

This will be on /tour, the twitter account, and anywhere else the description is displayed.

Yes?

Comment: This is Community Team approved and we'll update it in all the places.

Comment: (+1) Thanks, Abby!